# Having trouble indexing this numpy array [Python]

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

So the array is called `lines` and looks like this:

[image: numpy array]

All I would like to do is index the 3rd column (all values in the rows). Which I thought would just be like this:

`lines[:,2]` which gives me this error:

`IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1`

So when I check the shape `lines.shape` I get:

`(1, 4)`

I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: The array you have shown above has shape `(x, 1, 4)`, so what you want is either flatten the redundant axis in the middle or `lines[..., 2]`

Comment: Thanks. How do you "flatten" the axis?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since the shape of the array in the picture do not match the information given by OP. The problem can not be reproduced.

Comment: @hmnoidk you could for example do `lines.reshape(-1, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You used nested list so If you want to get list

You can get first three row by

```
lines[:3]
```

If you want only the third row

```
lines[2][0]
```

Also, I created an array similar to yours.

```
x = np.array([[[1,2,3,4]],
             [[5,6,7,8]],
             [[5,6,7,8]],
             [[5,6,7,8]],
             [[5,6,7,8]]])
```

and

```
x.shape => (5, 1, 4)
```

You have something wrong with the shape.